# What is the motivation for the "or" operator to not return a bool?

Tags: python, operators, boolean

First, the code:

```
>>> False or 'hello'
'hello'
```

This surprising behavior lets you check if `x` is not `None` and check the value of `x` in one line:

```
>>> x = 10 if randint(0,2) == 1 else None
>>> (x or 0) > 0
# depend on x value...
```

Explanation: `or` functions like [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html):

> if x is false, then y, else x

No language that I know lets you do this. So, why does Python?

Comment: Do you mean `x or x > 0`?  And this is short-circuit evaluation -- lots of languages let you do it.

Comment: Javascript: ``val || default``?

Comment: The real question is why **shouldn't** this be a feature of Python? Why should the assumption be you can't do something? Does this have any negative effect at all?

Comment: `x or 0 > 0` doesn't let you depend on the `x` value. In fact, it has no effect at all. Maybe you meant `x = x or 0`? But even so, that's an odd thing—and it could just as easily be handled in the line above by doing `x = 10 if randint(0, 2)==1 else 0` instead of `else None`. So… actually, I have no clue what you intended.

Comment: @SamMussmann i mean:  (None or 0) < 1 (which is True).

Answer (score 15):

It sounds like you're combining two issues into one.

First, there's the issue of short-circuiting. Marcin's answer addresses this issue perfectly, so I won't try to do any better.

Second, there's `or` and `and` returning the last-evaluated value, rather than converting it to bool. There are arguments to be made both ways, and you can find many languages on either side of the divide.

Returning the last-evaluated value allows the `functionCall(x) or defaultValue` shortcut, avoids a possibly wasteful conversion (why convert an `int` `2` into a `bool` `1` if the only thing you're going to do with it is check whether it's non-zero?), and is generally easier to explain. So, for various combinations of these reasons, languages like C, Lisp, Javascript, Lua, Perl, Ruby, and VB all do things this way, and so does Python.

Always returning a boolean value from an operator helps to catch some errors (especially in languages where the logical operators and the bitwise operators are easy to confuse), and it allows you to design a language where boolean checks are strictly-typed checks for `true` instead of just checks for nonzero, it makes the type of the operator easier to write out, and it avoids having to deal with conversion for cases where the two operands are different types (see the `?:` operator in C-family languages). So, for various combinations of these reasons, languages like C++, Fortran, Smalltalk, and Haskell all do things this way.

---

In your question (if I understand it correctly), you're using this feature to be able to write something like:

```
if (x or 0) < 1:
```

When `x` could easily be `None`. This particular use case isn't very useful, both because the more-explicit `x if x else 0` (in Python 2.5 and later) is just as easy to write and probably easier to understand (at least Guido thinks so), but also because `None < 1` is the same as `0 < 1` anyway (at least in Python 2.x, so you've always got at least one of the two options)… But there are similar examples where it *is* useful. Compare these two:

```
return launchMissiles() or -1

return launchMissiles() if launchMissiles() else -1
```

The second one will waste a lot of missiles blowing up your enemies in Antarctica twice instead of once.

---

If you're curious why Python does it this way:

Back in the 1.x days, there *was* no `bool` type. You've got falsy values like `None`, `0`, `[]`, `()`, `""`, etc., and everything else is true, so who needs explicit `False` and `True`? Returning `1` from `or` would have been silly, because `1` is no more true than `[1, 2, 3]` or `"dsfsdf"`. By the time `bool` was added (gradually over two 2.x versions, IIRC), the current logic was already solidly embedded in the language, and changing would have broken a lot of code.

So, why didn't they change it in 3.0? Many Python users, including BDFL Guido, would suggest that you shouldn't use `or` in this case (at the very least because it's a violation of "TOOWTDI"); you should instead store the result of the expression in a variable, e.g.:

```
missiles = launchMissiles()
return missiles if missiles else -1
```

And in fact, Guido has stated that he'd like to ban `launchMissiles() or -1`, and that's part of the reason he eventually accepted the ternary `if`-`else` expression that he'd rejected many times before. But many others disagree, and Guido is a  *benevolent* DFL. Also, making `or` work the way you'd expect everywhere else, while refusing to do what you want (but Guido doesn't want you to want) here, would actually be pretty complicated.

---

So, Python will probably always be on the same side as C, Perl, and Lisp here, instead of the same side as Java, Smalltalk, and Haskell.

Comment: Just wrote a quick fortran program.  Gfortran (at least) short-circuits.  When I first read this question, I didn't think it was about short-circuiting either (+1).  The fact that `or` and `and` don't return boolean values was one of the things that really surprised me at first with python.  After a while though, you get used to it (and learn to use it to play some neat tricks :)

Comment: @mgilson: Doesn't `gfortran` have 3000 flags to control which Fortran 77 dialect it's using? Anyway, am I at least right about Fortran returning boolean? BTW, I was also surprised that Python `or` and `and` don't return bool (or `1` and `0`, because there was no `bool` yet), but not quite for the same reason. I expected that, given the chance to be like Smalltalk and C++, or like Perl and C, Python would have chosen the former… But once I realized that `1` wasn't anything special (and really, `True` still isn't), it made sense.

Comment: FWIW, Python 3.x does not allow `None < 1` (raises `TypeError`).

Comment: From 3.8 one can `return launched if (launched := launchMissiles()) else -1`. This way the number of launched missiles is the same as `return launchMissiles() or -1`

Answer (score 10):

> No language that i know lets you do this. So, why Python do?

Then you don't know many languages. I can't think of one language that I do know that does not exhibit this "shortcircuiting" behaviour.

It does it because it is useful to say:

```
a = b or K
```

such that a either becomes b, if b is not None (or otherwise falsy), and if not it gets the default value K.

Comment: "I can't think of one language that I do know that does not"

Comment: Well, Guido doesn't think that particular use case is useful, and would like to ban it, and in fact part of the reason he agreed to add `b if b else k` was to convince people to stop doing it… but trying to make `or` work in a reasonable way without allowing this use case would make things much more complicated. Anyway, +1 because the general idea is right, and it's nicely explained and concise.

Comment: @abarnert Guido has a number of unusual and unpopular opinions, such as the idea that reduce is redundant and difficult to use. I could add more use cases, but I don't think it would aid OP's understanding much more.

Comment: @Marcin: Fortran, Pascal, and Algol68 don't do short-circuit. (Well, many Pascals do, but original and ISO don't, and Algol gives you a way to define your own short-circuit operators.) Also, many lazy languages technically don't do short-circuit because they don't need to. But somehow, I doubt the OP is coming to Python from Fortran or LazyML…

Comment: @abarnert I don't know Pascal, and I'm glad to have forgotten Fortran.  Arguably lazy languages all short circuit, because that's all shortcircuiting is: lazy evaluation of the `or` expression. I'm also innocent of Algol.

Comment: "I can't think of one language that I do know that does not" c++, c# java, PHP etc. they all return boolean value! think again.

Comment: @Marcin: A lazy language technically doesn't need to short-circuit, because you can "evaluate" both branches no matter what, and as long as nobody ever calls for the value of a branch it doesn't matter that it was evaluated. But some of them—including Haskell—actually _do_ short-circuit anyway.

Comment: @mclafee C and C++ definitely short circuit. Try it. Only PHP, of the languages you mention, is not statically typed, which accounts for why the value is folded to a numeric type.

Comment: @Marcin: I believe he's talking about failing to convert to bool, not about short-circuiting.

Comment: @abarnert That sounds like a distinction without a difference. Can you think of any code that demonstrates the distinction?

Comment: @Marcin: Of course! `x = [] or [1, 2, 3]` sets `x` to `[1, 2, 3]` in Python. The equivalent in C++ or Haskell sets `x` to `True`. That's a _huge_ difference.

Comment: @abarnert I'm talking about the distinction you are positing between short circuiting and lazy evaluation.

Comment: @abarnert -- I believe that `fortran` permits short circuiting, but doesn't force the compiler to do it.  (I came to `python` from `fortran` :)

Comment: @Marcin: I don't think I could explain it in a comment, but I'll bet the documentation for `Control.Shortcircuit` explains it.

Comment: @Marcin c++ java ...  do shortcircuiting, but return boolean! NOT the object. try this: "(None or 0) < 1" in java... put your hands on your head first...

Comment: @mgilson: OK, I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @mclafee: The way your question was written, it seems to combine two questions into one, and the one most people thought you were asking is the one you were less interested in. But see my answer for the one you _are_ interested in (unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: @mclafee As I've explained already in a comment, it's because those are statically typed languages.

Answer (score 6):

Actually a number of languages do.  See Wikipedia about [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

For the reason ***why*** short-circuit evaluation exists, wikipedia writes:

> If both expressions used as conditions are simple boolean variables,
>   it can be actually faster to evaluate both conditions used in boolean
>   operation at once, as it always requires a single calculation cycle,
>   as opposed to one or two cycles used in short-circuit evaluation
>   (depending on the value of the first).

Comment: Your quote is not providing reasons *for* the existence of short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: I think the question is more about returning the first non-false-like object, instead of a boolean. C does this; C++ and Java don't.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is not surprising, and it's quite straightforward if you consider Python has the following features regarding **or**, **and** and **not** logical operators:

- **Short-circuit evaluation**: it only evaluates operands up to where it needs to.
- **Non-coercing result**: the result is one of the operands, not coerced to `bool`.

And, additionally:

- The **Truth Value** of an object is ***False*** only for `None`, `False`, `0`, `""`, `[]`, `{}`. Everything else has a truth value of ***True*** (*this is a simplification; the correct definition is in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)*)

Combine those features, and it leads to:

- **or** : if the **first** operand evaluates as ***True***, short-circuit there and return it. Or return the 2nd operand.
- **and**: if the **first** operand evaluates as ***False***, short-circuit there and return it. Or return the 2nd operand.

It's easier to understand if you generalize to a chain of operations:

```
>>> a or b or c or d

>>> a and b and c and d
```

Here is the "rule of thumb" I've memorized to help me easily predict the result:

- **or** : returns the *first "**truthy**"* operand it finds, or the last one.
- **and**: returns the *first "**falsy**"* operand it finds, or the last one.

As for your question, on ***why*** python behaves like that, well... I think because it has some very neat uses, and it's quite intuitive to understand. A common use is a series of fallback choices, the first "found" (ie, *non-falsy*) is used. Think about this silly example:

```
drink = getColdBeer() or pickNiceWine() or random.anySoda or "meh, water :/"
```

Or this real-world scenario:

```
username = cmdlineargs.username or configFile['username'] or DEFAULT_USERNAME
```

Which is much more concise *and* elegant than the alternative.

As many other answers have pointed out, Python is not alone and many other languages have the same behavior, for both short-circuit (I believe *most* current languanges are) and non-coercion.

Comment: Contrary to this answer, Python does not have OR, AND and NOT operators. It has or, and and not.

Comment: @gwideman , following your suggestion I changed the uppercase occurrences and a few other case / spelling improvements

Answer (score 1):

"No language that i know lets you do this. So, why Python do?"  You seem to assume that all languages should be the same.  Wouldn't you expect innovation in programming languages to produce unique features that people value?

You've just pointed out why it's useful, so why wouldn't Python do it?  Perhaps you should ask why other languages don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the special features of the Python or operator out of Boolean contexts. The rule of thumb is still that the result of your Boolean expressions is the first `true` operand or the last in the line.

Notice that the logical operators (or included) are evaluated before the assignment operator `=`, so you can assign the result of a Boolean expression to a variable in the same way you do with a common expression:

```py
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> var1 = a or b
>>> var1
1
>>> a = None
>>> b = 2
>>> var2 = a or b
>>> var2
2
>>> a = []
>>> b = {}
>>> var3 = a or b
>>> var3
{}
```

Here, the `or` operator works as expected, returning the first `true` operand or the last operand if both are evaluated to `false`.