# Summation Combination code

Tags: python, combinatorics

Hi I am new to Python and am trying to solve a coding challenge where the objective is to create a function which takes an array of integers (both negative and positive) and a target value (also an integer) and then outputs true if any combinations of the numbers sum up to the target value, which will always be larger than any other single element in the input array. I tried to do this but horribly failed. I found someone else's code who did it in 2 lines, but I have no idea how it works and was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. Here is the code

```
def subsetsum(target, arr):
  if len(arr) == 0:
    return target == 0


  return subsetsum(target, arr[1:]) or subsetsum(target - arr[0], arr[1:])
```

I mean I don't even see where they sum up the numbers and compare to the target, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should read some basic stuff about recursion and you'll understand the code. Also try to track down the function step by step by taking some example values and the lights will turn on. Btw. you can try to convert the recursion into a for loop (every recursion can be converted), which is probably a good start/exercise.

Comment: Here is a discussion on the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393200/what-does-or-do-in-a-python-return-statement-explanation-of-list-subset-sum

Comment: Awesome. I did not know that this was referred to as recursion and I would love to read up on the theory, would you have any suggestions septi??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their solution uses recursion to express all possible combinations of the numbers in a pretty clever way. But clever does not always mean readable or easy to understand (which all code should be) so don't feel bad for not getting it right away. Personally, I would *not* consider this good code.

The simplest way to think of it is to work backwards.

- What happens if `arr` has 0 elements? Well, it's explicitly checked at the beginning of the function: it can only be a solution to the problem if `target` is already 0. Let's refer to this special case of `subsetsum` (where `arr` is `[]`) as `is_zero`, because that's all it does.
- What happens if `arr` has 1 element `[x]`? For a solution to exist, you have to get `target` by either including or not including `x` in the sum. This is done by converting the problem in to the 0-element version, as `arr[1:]` will be the empty list (`[]`). The first part of the `or` expression, `subsetsum(target, arr[1:])`, ignores `x` and basically asks if `is_zero(target)`. The second part of the expression includes `x` in the sum by asking if `is_zero(target - x)`. Try it with `arr = [9]`. You get `True` if `is_zero(target)` OR if `is_zero(target - 9)`. Which makes sense, right? If the target is 0 or 9, then `[0]` or `[9]` are solutions to the problem, respectively.
- What happens if `arr` has 2 elements `[x, y]`? Again, the problem is reduced into the 1-element-smaller version, as `arr[1:]` is just `[y]`. So, is there a solution in `subsetsum(target, [y])` OR is there a solution in `subsetsum(target - x, [y])`. Try it with `[3, 9]`. The first part of the expression ignores 3 and evaluates `True` if `target` is 9 or 0. The second part includes 3 and evaluates True if `target - 3` is 9 or 0 (i.e. if `target` is 12 or 3). Thus, it "tries" all possible combinations: `[]`, `[9]`, `[3]`, and `[9, 3]`.
- `subsetsum(target, [x, y, z])` is reduced to `subsetsum(target, [y, z])` OR `subsetsum(target - x, [y, z])`, and so on...

Looking from the top down now, what happens is that for every element in `arr`, the question is split into two subquestions of "is there a solution if we *do not* include this element?" and "is there a solution if we *do* include this element?" That way, you end up trying all `2**len(arr)` combinations.

A much cleaner (and more efficient) solution to this problem is definitely possible using Python's really sweet module `itertools`, but I don't have time to write it at the moment. I may try it tomorrow just for fun, though.

Edit: Here's my more readable (and probably faster) version.

```
import itertools

def subsetsum(target, arr):
    for subset_len in range(len(arr) + 1):
        if any(sum(subset) == target for subset in itertools.combinations(arr, subset_len)):
            return True
    return False
```

It simply finds all subsets, starting with length 0 (so `[]`) and working up to length `len(arr)`, and checks if any of them sum to `target`. Python is a beautiful language!

Comment: Thank you so much for your very detailed answer and explanation, it was very illuminating. I would have used that module but for the coding challenges we are not allowed to import modules.

Answer (score 0):

**edit** There's a bug in that code (depending on whether you think there is a combination of the numbers in `[1]` that sum up to `0`).  Try

```
subsetsum(0,[1])
> True
```

I explain a bit more below.
**end edit**

So I think the challenge in understanding the code isn't so much about Python as about understanding a recursive function.

Let's assume that the function `subsetsum` works for lists of length less than N.  Now let's take some list of length N.  If there is a subset that sums to the target it either involves the first element (`arr[0]`) or it doesn't.  So we'll break this into two problems - checking if there is a subset that has the first element, and checking if there is a subset that doesn't.

Note that `arr[1:]` is an array of length N-1 starting with the second element of `arr`.

So if there is a subset that does not involve `arr[0]`, then `subsetsum(target,arr[1:])` will give `True`.  If there is a subset that involves `arr[0]` then `subsetsum(target-arr[0],arr[1:])` will return `True`.  If neither holds then it's going to return `False`.

So basically whether this works for `N` depends on whether it works for `N-1`, which depends on whether it works for `N-2` etc.  Finally we get down to length 0.  If the target is 0, at this point, it should return `True`.  If not, the `False`, or at least, that's what the person writing this code thought.  I disagree.  Explanation of the bug below.

---

Personally, I would argue that there is a bug in this code.  If I give it any list and a target of 0, it'll return `True`.  <strike>The test should be that when it gets down to a length 1 list, is the target equal to that one value.</strike>  The test should be if the first element is the target, and if it gets down to a length 0 list, it's failed.

```
def subsetsum(target, arr):
  if len(arr)==0:
    return False
  elif arr[0]==target:
    return True    
  else:
    return subsetsum(target, arr[1:]) or subsetsum(target - arr[0], arr[1:])
```

Comment: That's not a bug at all. `subsetsum(0, [1,2])` returns `True` because `[]` is a subset of `[1, 2]`.

Comment: And (as a professional mathematician) I argue that there is no combination  of numbers in `[]` that sums to 0.

Comment: That's a matter of definitions, not a bug. Since OP says the code solves the problem, it's safe to assume her or his definition of the problem includes the empty set as a "combination".

Comment: I've added a little more discussion right at the top where I claim there's a bug.  I agree that it's a matter of definitions (hence my comment "Personally, I would argue that there is a bug in this code" where I explain more detail).