# In this very basic code i can't figure out what's the sytax error here in line 6 is (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

```
myName = input("Hey there, what's your name?")
print("Hello",myName,"!")
print("Here's a game called ''Guess my number'', in this game you will have to guess my number in 5 tips, I will think of a number between 1 and 20.")

ready = input("Are you readyyyy!?")
if ready = "yes" or "yeah" or "totally" or "hell yeah" or "yupp" or "yepp" or "uhumm" or "sure": <-- here's the problem it says, at "sure"'s 1st "-sign
    print("Let's go!")
    loop = "y"
else:
    print("I'm sorry to hear that.")
    loop "n"
```

Could please anyone help, beginner here. I tried to delete and add new word, I restared the program and the computer because there's something clearly wrong. If I delete a word like "sure" the pointer will still point to the same exact place but there's nothing there...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior

Answer (score 4):

You're using a single `=` sign in your `if` statement. That's not allowed. If you want to check for equality, you'll need to use `==`. The `=` operator is only for assignment statements.

While changing `=` to `==` will fix the syntax error, your code still won't work exactly right. That's because `==` will not be distributed over all the `or` options you show. The expression `a == b or c` gets interpreted as `(a == b) or c`, and if `c` is "truthy" (as any non-empty string will be), the expression will be considered true.

Instead, you probably want to use something like `if ready in {"yes", "yeah", "totally"}`. This creates a constant `set` object and tests if the value of the `ready` variable is in the set (which is a fast check).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response and I'm sorry for the silly question, I'm just starting out my first language and I'm kinda a kid, so..., but thanks anyway . :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `=` instead of a `==` in your if statement. However, I would recommend doing `if ready.lower() in {"yes", "yeah", "totally", "hell yeah", "yupp", "yepp"}` to account for them using all uppercase.

Also, you seem to be missing your actual loop statements. I noticed you had variables named loop that are 'y' and 'n' but don't actually use them. You should also do something like this:

```
myName = input("Hey there, what's your name?")
print("Hello",myName,"!")
print("Here's a game called ''Guess my number'', in this game you will have to guess my number in 5 tips, I will think of a number between 1 and 20.")
loop = True

while loop:
    ready = input("Are you readyyyy!?")
    if ready.lower() in {"yes", "yeah", "totally", "hell yeah", "yupp", "yepp", "uhumm", "sure"}:
        print("Let's go!")
        loop = False
        #To break out of the while loop that will keep asking them when they are ready
    else:
        print("I'm sorry to hear that.")
```