# Logic behind Form(request.POST or None)

Tags: python, django

What's the logic behind `request.POST or None`? I haven't seen such thing in Python projects except Django.

Since `or` operator returns **True** or **False** values, how is it possible that if `request.POST` isn't `None`, the `Form` knows it and takes post as an argument?

```
form = MyModelForm(request.POST or None)
```

In fact, the result should be `Form(True)` if `request.POST` isn't `None`, otherwise `Form(False)`.

How it works?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13870633/771848.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The use of `or` in this case does not evaluate to `True` or `False`, but returns one of the objects.

Keep in mind that `or` is evaluated from left to right.

When the QueryDict `request.POST` is empty, it takes a Falsy value, so the item on *RHS* of the `or` operation is selected (which is `None`), and the form is initialized without *vanilla* arguments (i.e. with `None`):

```
form = MyModelForm()
```

Otherwise, when `request.POST` is  not empty, the form is initialized with the QueryDict:

```
form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: `the form is initialized without arguments` -- No, it is initialized with one argument: `None`

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I assume `None` would not be used by the form's `__init__` in any way. But you are right