# How do i check if one or more certain characters are an a string?

Tags: python, string

I want to check if two strings contain "\n" or "\r" using just one if statement not two, and is there any way to do this or must I use a for loop?

I tried tweaking the if statement in many ways but it seems like I just cant get it right, so must I use a for loop or two if statements?

```
def singleline_diff_format(line1, line2, idx):
    """
    Inputs:
      line1 - first single line string
      line2 - second single line string
      idx   - index at which to indicate difference
    Output:
      Returns a three line formatted string showing the location
      of the first difference between line1 and line2.

      If either input line contains a newline or carriage return,
      then returns an empty string.

      If idx is not a valid index, then returns an empty string.
     """
    equals = "=" * (idx)
    min_length = min(len(line1), len(line2))

    if "\n" or "\r" in line1 or line2:
        return ""
    else:
        return line1 +  "\n{}^".format(equals) + "\n" + line2 

print(singleline_diff_format("abcd", "abed", 2))
print(singleline_diff_format("abcd \nhey man", "abed", 2))    
print(singleline_diff_format("abcd", "abed", 5))
```

I expect

abcd

==^

abed

abcd

hey man

==^

abed

abcd

=====^

abed

But I just get empty strings which means that the if statement isn't working properly.

Comment: `if "\n" or "\r" in line1 or line2` test this line in the REPL, I don't think it does what you think.

Comment: `or` conditions do not work like that. you have to write complete conditions on either side such as `"\n" in line1 or "\r" in line1` and so on etc

Comment: @ParitoshSingh oh so this is where i got it wrong, i just thought there was a more pythonic and compact way to do it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb no it doesnt do what i though

Comment: Since both line1 and line2 should be strings, you could however append them if you absolutely do not want to use a for-loop: `if '\n' in line1+line2 or '\r' in line1+line2: ...`

Comment: @RoyM that worked as well thank u very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python "or" operator weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(char in line for char in ('\n',  '\r') for line in (line1, line2)):
    ....
```

This will be `True` if any of the 4 conditions `'\n' in line1`, `'\n' in line2`,`'\r' in line1`, `'\r' in line2` is `True - and is much more compact...

Answer (score 0):

Your logic isn't doing what you intend and when you do match, you are returning an empty string.
if "\n" or "\r" in line1 or line2:
        return ""

Try:
if ("\n" or "\r") in (line1 or line2):
    return f'{line1}\n=\n{line2}'

Comment: `or` doesnt work how you think either. Your condition essentially resolved to `if "\r" in line2`.