# Understanding the OR operator

Tags: python

Just started learning Python in IDLE and came across this:

```
numArray = [1, 2, 3, 1]
(1 or 7) in numArray #returns True
(7 or 1) in numArray #returns False
```

Why does the (7 or 1) return False?

Comment: When you saw this, you should have run `7 or 1` in Python. Upon seeing that the return value was 7, you should have googled `python or operator`. You would then understand why the output was the way it was.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior

Answer (score 2):

The `or` operation returns the first `True` operand between two values. If all operands are `False`, it returns the last operand. Example:

```
>>> 7 or 1
7
>>> bool(7)
True
>>> 
>>> False or 0
0
>>> bool(0)
False
>>>
```

So it sees that `7` is not in the list and returns `False`

> *If you’re testing two objects using or in Python, then the operator will return the first object that evaluates to true or the last object in the expression, regardless of its truth value*  - https://realpython.com/python-or-operator/

Comment: The statement `Using or between two values returns the first value` is incorrect.

Comment: @blhsing Made an edit

Comment: The edited statement is better, but should really say that the `or` operator returns the first *truthy* operand it evaluates from left to right, and if neither is truthy, returns the last operand.

Comment: @blhsing Also edited the code according to it

Answer (score 2):

This is because `or` is evaluated left to right, for truthiness. Both `1` and `7` are non-zero, so they're "truthy."

You are telling Python to do the following with your logic.

> **Is 1 or 7 not a zero?**
>
> Python stops at `1`. `1` is truthy. So whatever is within the `()`
>   resolves to `1`. `1` is also in your list.
>
> **Is 7 or 1 not a zero?**
>
> Python stops right at `7`, `7` is truthy. Whatever is within the
>   `()` resolves to `7`. `7` is *not* in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Your intent is something like `7 in numArray or 1 in numArray`, but `or` doesn't factor like that. `7 or 1` is evaluated first, then the *result* is used as the first operand for `in`. Since `7 or 1` evaluates to `7`, you are testing if `7 in numArray` is true.

It looks like you want to use the `any` function instead.

```
any(x in numArray for x in [1, 7])  # True
any(x in numArray for x in [7, 1])  # Also True
```

The difference between the two is the first will return sooner; as soon as it sees that `1 in numArray` is true, it will immediately return without bothering to check any more values. The second one sees that 7 is not in `numArray`, then moves on to the next value.

Answer (score 0):

```
numArray = [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Now let's see the operations:

```
(1 or 7) = 1 
# The or operator stops evaluating when it finds an operand True. In this case, it stops at 1
```

`1` is in the array and that's why `True`

```
(7 or 1) = 7
# The or operator stops when it finds an operand True. In this case, it stops at 7
```

`7` is not in the array and that's why `False`

When you do:

```
(0 or 7) 
# The result would be `7` as the first operand is `0` and considered as `false` and hence the second operand is evaluated.
```

However, `and` operator stops evaluating when it finds an operand 'False` from left to right otherwise, evaluates till the last.

```
(1 and 7) = 7
# Evaluates till the end since it did not find False and results in 7

(7 and 1) = 7
# Evaluates till the end since it did not find False and results in 1

(0 and 5) = 0
# The first operand is False and it stops here and results in 0
```