# Why is the last number returned when putting "and" in python?

Tags: python, console, operators, return-value

I was playing around with the console in python and I found something interesting. When I put they keyword "and" I get the last number, and when I put the keyword "or" I get the first number. For example:

```
>>> 1 and 2
2

>>> 2 and 1
1

>>> 1 or 2
1

>>> 2 or 1
2
```

This also applies for multiple numbers:

```
>>> 1 and 3 and 2
2

>>> 3 or 2 or 1
3
```

You can mix and match:

```
>>> 3 and 1 or 2
1

>>> 2 or 3 and 1
2
```

My question is why is this true? How does this work? I would appreciate if anybody could shed some light on the matter.

Thanks.

EDIT: See the comment left by @Hedgy for a link to a similar question that has a detailed response.

Comment: Seems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior might be similar to your question.

Comment: So is Python's documentation for `and` unclear or did you just not read it?

Comment: @Hedgy That was a huge help, it explained everything. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python "or" operator weird behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870378/python-or-operator-weird-behavior)

Comment: Yes @Hedgy that’s the same link you shared earlier. It answers my question perfectly thank you.

Comment: @IvanBurgert Sorry about that, I didn't meant to send it twice.